# how to do pagination in python bigtable

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to do the pagination using python in bigtable while reading TB's of data  but didn't get any idea. Could you please help or can attach the sample code of python pagination in bigtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [scan over your table](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data#prefix) like so and read_rows will provide you with an iterator:

```
def read_prefix(project_id, instance_id, table_id):
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)
    table = instance.table(table_id)
    prefix = "phone#"
    end_key = prefix[:-1] + chr(ord(prefix[-1]) + 1)

    row_set = RowSet()
    row_set.add_row_range_from_keys(prefix.encode("utf-8"),
                                    end_key.encode("utf-8"))

    rows = table.read_rows(row_set=row_set)
    for row in rows:
        print_row(row)
```

read_rows returns a [PartialRowsData](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/blob/master/google/cloud/bigtable/row_data.py#L352) object that handles retries, so if you need a certain number of items for your actions, you could just add a counter in the for loop like this and it should have the same effect as pagination:

```
count = 0
page_size = 10
for row in rows:
    print_row(row)
    count++
    if count % page_size == 0:
        # Do your action based on page size
```

There are more examples show